# How can I open or import FLT (OpenFlight) files in Blender (mac)?

Tags: interface

What the headline says - how to open/view .flt (OpenFlight) in Blender 2.79?

Comment: As there are more type of FLT files, which one are you referring to? ArchInfo? OpenFlight? Adobe Image filter? E-on Vue? Please explain in your question what type of file you are referring to

Comment: [Google is your friend](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=blender+OpenFlight+.flt)

Answer (score 4):

In Blender version 2.42a - 2.46 there is an option to load OpenFlight FLT files. In later versions this addon has been removed (most likely due to the lack of support by the community).

Best way currently is to download blender version 2.46 and import the FLT file (File → Import → OpenFlight(.flt)). Save the blend file and open this blend file with the blender version of your liking.

Second option is to find a developer who will migrate and maintain the OpenFlight plugin.

More information of the plugin can be found at https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.4/Py/Scripts/Import/Openflight_flt

Comment: Thanks for the help in finding the dated Blender version, I'll be good from here on I think. Much appreciated!